# Rails_admin content of a model not being shown in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, pg

I have created a model called 'Ad' and have created several row, but none is being shown in the table, only the number of ads is shown. I have many other models which work perfectly fine. What could possibly cause this? Is the name too short?

[image]

**Update:**
I have tried creating a project with just the 'Ad' model and rails_admin and the content also does not appear. If I change the name to advertisement then it works. So the name seems to be the problem.

Comment: Can you share your view file?

Comment: @StéphaneJ. I think rails_admin generate the view for the dashboard automatically.

Comment: @StéphaneJ. I believe this is the view in question. https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Adblock is hiding the content. Paused it and problem solved.